# MySQL datetime how do I set it with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 rows in my DB **last_active** & **created_on** that are both datetime stamps when I create the record how do I set created_on.

I'm assuming the Last_active would be [set] the same [way] if not how do I set that as well?

In case you missed it in the title I'm using PHP.

Comment: You are looking for the format for mysql dates in php?  You can see all the mysql-based functions you can call on what you pass into the query here.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into yourtable (last_active, created_on) values (now(), now());
```

Complete list of MySQL's date/time functions is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: don't know why i wasn't able to find that in a search i completely forgot about that

Comment: I think, that I would capitalize some of the things in the query though.

INSERT INTO
    yourtable
(last_active, created_on)
VALUES
(NOW(), NOW()

Comment: that's just for legibility. SQL by itself is case-insensitive.

Comment: @Dennis - .. and I think I would drop the comma after "I think" to be pedantic

Comment: For sure! You're 100% right. It was just a suggestion - i don't want to take any credit from your answer. I think it is nice, that you give code example and link to the function! (gave it +1 as the first) :-)

@Richard: LOL! Funnyness +1. Don't dare giving it though. But my english wasn't good enough to try and explain with words that I would capitalize some parts.

Sorry for my comment then :-)